# Are Angular UI and Angular Material mutually exclusive?

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-ui, angular-material

To use Angular Material (1.x), do we need Angular UI. If I use Angular Material alone, will I get features similar to Angular UI (apart from Material Design)?

Are they mutually exclusive, or dependent on one another?

Basically, I want to use Material Design with Angular JS. I'm new to both, so I'm unclear whether I need to use Angular UI as well.

Can someone summarize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular material was created to follow Google Material Design - in that design a lot of things are documented like animation speed, paddings, fonts, etc. Obviously angular UI do not follow these rules.

However, angular material is far from being completed framework - so you always need to use something else - i.e. in angular material there are no tables at all.

Some things you can find in both - i.e. $uibModal vs $mdToast.

To sum, you can use both at the same time, but you will need to fix look and feel.

Comment: then seems like choosing Angular Material is bad choice for now. For Angular 2, is there Angular UI or just Angular material 2?

Comment: For Angular 2, the AngularUI team is developing ng-bootstrap, here: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io